# match validator in mongoose drives me crazy

Tags: mongoose

I'm trying to use the built-in match validator. Here's my scheme:

```
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    prodName: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
      maxlength: 25,
    },
    prodDescription: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      maxlength: 80,
    },
    prodPrice: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      match: /[0-9.,]+/,
      maxLength: 8,
    },
    photo: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
    },
  },
)
```

It validate everything. What I'm missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer, for an email here: 
(this line goes in your schema file)

```
userSchema.path('email').validate(value => /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.test(value))
```

I used RFC5322 found here: http://emailregex.com/